# Background image set in CSS not working in Edge mobile but work in Chrome

Tags: mobile, background-image, microsoft-edge

I have this CSS in a Razor Page project:

```
    body {
        background: url('../images/graphics/myimage.jpeg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

The main body tag and link to the style sheet are in _Layout.cshtml.

The background image works fine *everywhere* except for pages other than index.cshtml in the mobile version of MS Edge browser; it works just fine in Chrome mobile. Works fine in *all* desktop browsers too.

I've only tested on Android.

Comment: Can you please inform us which version of the MS Edge Android browser you are using for this test? Did you see any error or just image is not displaying? If the image is large size then it may take some time to get a load with a slow internet connection. Try to pass the path like this '/images/background_img1.jpeg'. check whether it helps to fix this issue.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? If your issue is solved now then you could share your solution here. If the issue still persists then you can share the current status of your issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I'm using Edge Mobile 45.03.4.4958 (updated May 18, 2020). It is not displaying any error. The size of the image does not matter since it displays just fine on the home page. AS I said in my original post, it displays just fine on every page if I use Chrome mobile.

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether you get the same results if you try to open the same page on any other Android phone with the Edge for the android browser installed? I suggest you go to Settings-> Privacy & security-> Clear browsing data and clear the browsing history, cookies and site data, and Cached images and files. then again try to check for the issue.

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache and viewed the site on another Android phone with the same results - everything works fine in Chrome but not in Edge. And on the second phone is was tested on a fresh install of Edge.

Comment: Did you try to pass the path like this '/images/background_img1.jpeg'? If you did not test this then I suggest you test it and let us know whether it is working or not. It may help to narrow down the issue. I suggest trying to create a new Razor project and just try to put the problematic code in it and make a test with it on the MS Edge for the Android browser to check for the result.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I come to the following conclusions:

1. Try restarting your Edge mobile and [cleaning up its cache](https://help.overdrive.com/en-us/0518.html).
2. Check whether the image cache settings of Edge are limited;
3. Perhaps the Edge mobile belongs to the third-party software on your phone, so its speed is slightly slower. In addition, its compatibility with your phone's operating system affects the page rendering process.You could try different models of mobile phones to test.

For more:[this link](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/common-microsoft-edge-problems-and-how-to-fix-them/).

If the background image still cannot be loaded in edge mobile, hopefully you could provide information about the more code or settings that is related to browser loading.